# Content disappeared in Storyboard editor

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xcode6, xcode-storyboard

Upon updating to Xcode Beta 7, I noticed that nothing was actually visible in my storyboard files. It currently looks like this (isn't it strange that the segues are all the same length now?)
[image]

The views are all grayed out in the menu on the left side as well. That appears as follows:
[image]

Also, the views load in the simulator as they did before. All the views are still there. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably designed your view's contents in another size class so they are greyed out. Try switching to w/any h/any and see if your elements reappear.

Comment: Yes! Size class was it! Thank you very much!